# Bulk Insert with dynamic mapping in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Currently, I'm using `Bulk Insert` statement to read the CSV files and add all rows to the SQL table.

```
BULK INSERT tablename
FROM 'D:\Import Files\file.csv'
WITH ( 
       FIRSTROW = 2,
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
       ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a');
```

But now I have a dynamic mapping for each file and stored in a table (File's Field Name = Database Field Name).

Mapping Table:

```
FileId  FileFieldName  DBFieldName

1       Order-Id       orderid
1       Order-Date     orderdate
2       Id             orderid
2       Orderedon      orderdate
```

I want to map the file field name with database fields and import the rows to the SQL table.

How to achieve dynamic mapping with `Bulk Insert` statement in SQL Server?

Comment: `BULK INSERT` is fast - and that's specifically **because** it doesn't support filtering, or converting, or other manipulations during insert. You can **either** live with that limitation and do your manipulations **after** the data has been bulk loaded - or then you give up on the speed of `BULK INSERT` and do your "normal" `INSERT` statements that can handle all those mappings etc. - take your pick.

Comment: Instead of using T-SQL for this, you would probably want to use something like C# and SqlBulkCopy class. (Not sure if you could also build a CLR UDF, so it would count doing with T-SQL).

Comment: @CetinBasoz, I have VBScript project and I don't think sqlBulkCopy can be support.

Comment: @vibhavbhavsar, why not. It is supported via Activex. Maybe you would want to visit foxite.com and search for it. I have uploaded the samples there along with the activex (codes are VFP but you could easily convert to vbscript). Or if you don't want to do that, still vbscript itself is better than trying to do this with T-SQL IMHO.

Comment: And probably the easiest would be to write a small C# code that would take only a bunch of lines.

Answer (score 1):

Write your dynamic map from the table to an XML file, then use [this syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#using-bulk-insert-and-xml-format-file) for `BULK INSERT`:

```
BULK INSERT tablename
   FROM 'D:\Import Files\file.csv'   
   WITH (FORMATFILE = 'D:\BCP\myFirstImport.xml');
```